# Solutions to $1 - \frac{r'^2}{2c^2} + \frac{r r''}{c^2}=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, sagemath

Sage says that$$\sqrt{2 \, c^{2} - e^{K_{1}} r\left(t\right)} e^{\left(-K_{1}\right)} = K_{2} + t$$$$-2\sqrt{2 \, c^{2} - e^{K_{1}} r\left(t\right)} e^{\left(-K_{1}\right)} = K_{2} + t$$are solutions to$$1 - \frac{r'^2}{2c^2} + \frac{r r''}{c^2}=0.$$Is that right?

Comment: You can solve for $r(t)$ in both equations and then substitute into the original equation and verify directly, of course.

Comment: $1/r^2$ is never zero, so the equation is equivalent to $1-r'^2/2c^2+rr''/c^2=0$, isn't it?

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, I forgot to delete that after copying and pasting. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
1-\frac{r'^2}{2c^2} + \frac{rr''}{c^2} = 0
$$

$$
r'' = r'\dfrac{d}{dr}r'
$$
thus
$$
1 - \frac{r'^2}{2c^2} + \frac{r}{c^2}r'\dfrac{d}{dr}r' = \frac{r}{2c^2}\dfrac{d}{dr}r'^2 - \frac{r'^2}{2c^2}+1
$$
let $y = \frac{r'^2}{2c^2}$ we find
$$
r\dfrac{dy}{dr} -y+1 = 0
$$
thus
$$
\dot{y} -\frac{1}{r}y = -\frac{1}{r}
$$
integrating factor methods
$$
y\mathrm{e}^{-\ln r} = -\int\frac{1}{r}\mathrm{e}^{-\ln r}dr + C_1
$$
$$
\frac{y}{r} = -\int \frac{1}{r^2}dr + C_1 = \frac{1}{r} +C_1
$$
leads to
$$
y = 1 + C_1r = \frac{r'^2}{2c^2}
$$
thus
$$
r'^2 = 2c^2\left(1 + C_1r\right)\implies r' = \pm\sqrt{1+C_1r}\sqrt{2}c
$$
and solve.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I think I found a way to solve the problem.  Start by multiplying both sides by $r'$.

$$r^{-2}r'+\frac1{2c^2}(-r^{-2}r'^3+2r^{-1}r'r'')=0$$

Note that the term in parentheses can be written as

$$(r^{-1}r'^2)'$$

Knowing this, we can integrate both sides to get

$$-r^{-1}+\frac{r^{-1}r'^2}{2c^2}=k_1,\frac{r'^2}{2c^2}=k_1r+1$$
$$r'^2=k_2r+2c^2,r'=\pm\sqrt{k_2r+2c^2}$$
$$\int\frac{dr}{\sqrt{k_2r+2c^2}}=\pm\int dt$$
$$\frac2{k_2}\sqrt{k_2r+2c^2}=\pm t+k_3$$
$$\sqrt{k_2r+2c^2}=\pm\frac{k_2t}2+k_4$$
$$k_2r+2c^2=\frac{k_2^2t^2}4\pm k_2k_4t+k_4^2$$

Comment: I stopped and posted what I had when the latex quit updating for some reason.  I had been going to solve for $r$, though I'm not sure what you'd prefer.  I'm sure you can take it from there.